# toolbar opacity is changed in a strange way - android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I have a toolbar which has a green background. Inside the code I don't change the opacity or the alpha value but in some cases the toolbar opacity is changed in a very strange way.
what are the possible reasons for this.

[image]

Here is the xml of the toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:visibility="visible">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlNormalToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_white"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_close_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_toolbar_back_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogoMSC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_msc_small"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_notification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_noti"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_st" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_notificationBadge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_12"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_mess"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_messages" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_messageBadge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_12"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_people"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_people_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_bell"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/bell" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_bell_crossed"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/crossed_bell" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_tree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_2"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_1"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_mark"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_alert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_mark"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlSearchToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/sv_search_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_item_list_divider"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:queryHint="Search"
        android:visibility="visible">

    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_search_back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/toolbar_item_padding" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The opacity changes when a dialog is shown on top, like on the image?

Comment: I just mean the toolbar above. I covered the other information below the toolbar because they are confedential.

Comment: @Chisko I have uploaded another image, a clearer one.

Comment: If the dialog is on top, it is expected